# Rails 3.2 Bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dialog, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem with BOOTSTRAP and RAILS 3.2, I can not to display my form.

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New Country', new_backend_country_path, class:"btn btn-primary", :id => 'create_country' %>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require backend/bootstrap-modal.js
//= require rails.validations

    $('#create_country').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf('#') == 0) {
            $(href).modal('open');
        } else {
            $.get(href, function(data) {
                $('<div class="modal fade" >' + data  + '</div>').modal();
            });
        }
    });
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal-window">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
    <h6>Loading...</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body center">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([:backend, @country], :remote => true) do |f| %>

  <% if @country.errors.any? %>
            <% @country.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <h4 class="alert_error"><%= msg %></h4>
            <% end %>
       <br>
  <% end %>

  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class =>"upper" %>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </fieldset>

    <footer>
        <div class="submit_link">
          <% if @country.new_record? %>
              <%= f.submit "Create", class:"alt_btn" %>
          <% else %>
              <%= f.submit "Update", class:"alt_btn" %>
          <% end %>
            <%= submit_tag "Cancel" %>
        </div>
    </footer>

<% end %>
```

My form is not displayed and into the MODAL DIALOG it gives me whole page with my menu and footer.

thank you for your help

Comment: You shouldn't mix old and new hash syntax, like `class:"btn btn-primary", :id => 'create_country'`. Use `class: "btn", id: "create_country"`.